# Android Studio - Error launching failed to load jvm dll

Tags: android, android-studio

It happened after I upgraded the new version.

It was good before the upgrade.
And doesn't look like the right path.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uC5q.png)

Can some one tell me how to do this?

I have the JAVA HOME environment.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpNba.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the new electric eel version of android studio. Yesterday (01/13/23) in the morning I downloaded the dolphin version at my work and with its installer I had no problems.

During the night I went to carry out the same process, but I had not realized that it was this new version, and then I had this problem.

Perhaps during today, I will be able to find the installer of the dolphin version in this link, however, until now, it is not available yet.

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem the solution is here
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247854802#comment12
i dowloaded Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable from here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170